# Inserting current timestamp and retrieving according to timezone

Tags: php, mysql

I have a "date" column of type `timestamp` in my table that is `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` (on update).
I retrieve it with PHP using: `date('H:i a', strtotime($message->date)`
But the time displayed is inconsistent for different database/server hosts (each has its own timezone).
Exampe of date format as shown in the database itself: `2018-05-06 20:20:22`

What is the way to make the timestamp more general (perhaps unix time in seconds), and then in PHP retrieve it based on the user's timezone?
Will I have to change the `INSERT` statement to explicitly insert a unix timestamp, or "CURRENT_TIMESTAMP" can do it too? (And then in PHP how to convert it)

Comment: Is your database field a timestamp type or a datetime type ?

Comment: timestamp, also added to main post, thanks

Comment: The usual approach is to use UTC internally everywhere (both in PHP and MySQL). But the important question is: do you know what the user's time zone is in the first place?

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the time zone which you need, 
let say you want the date in 'America/Los_Angeles' then you can get the time like this

```
$date = $message->date; //your date
$tz = new DateTimeZone('America/Los_Angeles'); // User's time zone

$date = new DateTime($date);
$date->setTimezone($tz);
echo $date->format('H:i a');
```

Comment: Thank you! it does change, but, it's still +1 hour. I think because the "CURRENT TIMESTAMP" on the mysql column is based on the clock of the server, and not the global time? (because the current timestamp shows the time on my country, perhaps I need to change it as well?) I will have to change current_timestamp to be that of unix time I think? But how?

Comment: You need to store the time in UTC and then you can print in whatever timezone you need